# Android: Send multiple images to server using MIME-multipart

Tags: android-volley, multipart

Here is my multipart message with the user token:

```
"url":"http://freedoctor.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com/reports/add",
"method": "POST",
"headers": 
{
  "authorization": "JWT token",
},
"mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
data: 
{
  file: [ multiple files that patient wants to upload],
  category: "like denstis"
}    
res:
{
  message: file upload success
}
```

This is my `MainActivity` class:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener 
{
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    private String selectedImagePath;
    private ArrayList<String> imagesPathList;
    Map<String, File> mFilePartData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);


        //Auth header
        Map<String, String> mHeaderPart= new HashMap<>();
        mHeaderPart.put("mimeType", "multipart/form-data;");
        mHeaderPart.put("access_token",
                           "token");

        //File part
        mFilePartData= new HashMap<>();
        // mFilePartData.put("file", new File(mFilePath));
        // mFilePartData.put("file", new File(mFilePath));

        //String part
        Map<String, String> mStringPart= new HashMap<>();
        mStringPart.put("profile_id","1");
        mStringPart.put("imageType", "ProfileImage");

        CustomMultipartRequest mCustomRequest = new    CustomMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, getBaseContext(), "http://freedoctor.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com/reports/add", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                Log.d("JSONObject",jsonObject.toString());

                Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener=null;
                listener.onResponse(jsonObject);
                System.out.println("listnernull");
                System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                      Log.d("VOLLEYError",volleyError.toString());

                Response.ErrorListener listener =null;
                listener.onErrorResponse(volleyError);
                System.out.println("ERRornull");
                System.out.println(volleyError.toString());
            }
        }, mFilePartData, mStringPart, mHeaderPart);    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
        {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) 
            {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                File file=new File(selectedImageUri.getPath());
                Log.d("FILE",file.toString());
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                mFilePartData.put("file", file);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) 
    {
        // just some safety built in
        if (uri == null) 
        {
            // TODO perform some logging or show user feedback
            return null;
        }

        String result = null;
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) 
        {
            int columnIndex = 0;
            try {
                columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                result = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.e("Whilegettingpathforfile", String.valueOf(e));
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (!cursor.isClosed()) {
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                    cursor = null;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("While closing cursor", String.valueOf(e));
                }
            }
        }    
        // this is our fallback here
        return uri.getPath();
    }
}
```

This is my `CustomMultipartRequest`:

```
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;

import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Map;

public class CustomMultipartRequest extends Request<JSONObject> 
{
    private final Response.Listener<JSONObject> mListener;
    private final Map<String, File> mFilePartData;
    private final Map<String, String> mStringPart;
    private final Map<String, String> mHeaderPart;    
    private MultipartEntityBuilder mEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    private HttpEntity mHttpEntity;
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomMultipartRequest(int method, Context mContext, `String url, Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener, `Response.ErrorListener errorListener, Map<String, File> mFilePartData, `Map<String, String> mStringPart, Map<String, String> mHeaderPart) 
     {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        mListener = listener;
        this.mFilePartData = mFilePartData;
        this.mStringPart = mStringPart;
        this.mHeaderPart = mHeaderPart;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        mEntityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        buildMultipartFileEntity();
        buildMultipartTextEntity();
        mHttpEntity = mEntityBuilder.build();
    }

    public static String getMimeType(Context context, String url) 
    {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(url));
        String mimeType = null;
        if (uri.getScheme().equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
            mimeType = cr.getType(uri);
        } else {
            String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri
                    .toString());
            mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(
                    fileExtension.toLowerCase());
        }
        return mimeType;


    }

    private void buildMultipartFileEntity() 
    {
        for (Map.Entry<String, File> entry : mFilePartData.entrySet()) {
            try {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                File file = entry.getValue();
                String mimeType = getMimeType(mContext, file.toString());
                mEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody(key, file, ContentType.create(mimeType), file.getName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void buildMultipartTextEntity() 
    {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mStringPart.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            if (key != null && value != null)
                mEntityBuilder.addTextBody(key, value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError 
    {
        return mHeaderPart;
    }


    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() 
    {
        return mHttpEntity.getContentType().getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError 
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            mHttpEntity.writeTo(bos);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
        }
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) 
    {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) 
    {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }    
}
```

I want to send multiple images to the server using MIME-multipart.
I am using volley.
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I want to send multiple images to the server using multipart.i am using volley.can anyone help me on this.

Comment: I improved A LOT of code formatting, some other formatting/spelling and the title.

Comment: @RahulKashyap did you get the answer??? actually I wan too send multiple image using volley multipart plz help me